# Potential energy of an object (with non-negligible size compared to distance from ground level)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

Let's say I have a cylindrical water tank (with area $A$ and height $h$), and the bottom of the tank is $H$ meter from the ground.

So what is the potential energy of the water tank? If the $h$ is negligible then we know that it is $mgH$, with $m$ the mass of the water tank, and $g$ the gravitational constant. But if the $h$ is not negligible compared to $H$, then the potential energy of the water tank is $mgH$, or $mg(h/2+H)$ or $mg(h+H)$?

My intuition told me that it should be $mg(h/2+H)$ (the energy acts at the middle of the tank). But I can't prove it, so what is the correct answer, and how to derive it?

Comment: You need to calculate the center of mass of the object. Then the total potential energy of the object is the same as a point mass with the same total mass placed at the center of mass.[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Assumption made**: incompressible liquid, gravitational acceleration is constant.

---

Let us consider ground to have zero potential. Since tank is at height H.
Initial height is H.

If we take elements of really small height **dh** from height **h** measured from bottom of the container.

Then mass of the element is: $$\ \rho \cdot A \cdot dh$$

Therefore the potential energy for the mass for small element is *mgh* in this case:
$$\rho \cdot A \cdot g \cdot dh \cdot h$$

On Integrating this finely chopped pieces (hypothetically chopped) of fluid in container:
$$\int_H^{h+H} \rho \cdot g \cdot A \cdot dh \cdot h = \int_H^{h+H} \rho \cdot g \cdot A \cdot dh \cdot h$$
$$\int_H^{h+H} \rho \cdot g \cdot A \cdot dh \cdot h = \rho \cdot g \cdot A  \cdot \frac{(h+H)^2 - Η^2}2$$

---

This is your **final answer** (since you can only find change in potential energy therefore delta is used):
$$\Delta U = \rho \cdot g \cdot A  \cdot \frac{(h+H)^2 - Η^2}2$$

Comment: Your answer doesn't make sense to me; in the limiting case where $h$ tends to $0$ I would expect to get $$\Delta U = \rho \cdot A \cdot H \cdot H$$, but this is not happening in your answer.

Comment: Sorry my previous answer was totally wrong. Now I have corrected it and made sure its 100% correct. Thanks for pointing it out and sorry for inconvenience. @Graviton

Comment: And if you are wondering what if **h=0** then it means there is no fluid since mass of whole fluid is given by $\rho \cdot A \cdot h$. But I think what you wanted to say was what if **h<<<H** then what we need to do is expand the square term: $$\rho \cdot g \cdot A \cdot \frac {h^2 + 2 \cdot h \cdot H + H^2 - H^2}2$$ on simplification and assuming since **h<<<H**, $h^2 \approx 0$. Therefore $$\Delta U = \rho \cdot g \cdot A \cdot \frac {2 \cdot h \cdot H}2 =  \rho \cdot g \cdot A \cdot h \cdot H $$ and since mass of whole fluid is $\rho \cdot A \cdot h$: $$\Delta U = m \cdot g \cdot h$$

Comment: @Graviton hope you like the updated answer and reason to your comment